# Shakesort in Python 3

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I've done the shakesort algorithm win \$O(N^2)\$ but it doesn't seem that \$O(N^2)\$ is correct because it takes 6-9 steps in the `while` loop for a list of 4 integers and \$4^2\$ is 8. ~1975 steps for 80 entries. I think that should be original. Do you have any tips and improvements for me?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Nov 25 20:02:33 2016
Shakesort Algorithm

@author: frye
"""
import random

def shakesort(workList):
    listLength = len(workList)
    listIndexDecr = listLength - 1
    listIndexIncr = 0
    xChanged = True
    step = 0

    if(listLength <= 1):
        return workList, 1
    # This will loop n times throught the whole list till the
    # list got looped without a change of number or sort
    while (True):
        step = step + 1 # For counting purpose
        # Init a new loop
        if(listIndexDecr <= 0):
            listIndexIncr = 0
            listIndexDecr = listLength - 1
            # Stop if the last loop had no sort!
            if(xChanged == False):
                break
            # Set it False again
            xChanged = False

        # Walk Forward
        if(workList[listIndexIncr] > workList[listIndexIncr+1]):
            tvar = workList[listIndexIncr+1] 
            workList[listIndexIncr+1] = workList[listIndexIncr]
            workList[listIndexIncr] = tvar
            xChanged = True
        listIndexIncr = listIndexIncr + 1

        # Walk back
        if(workList[listIndexDecr-1] > workList[listIndexDecr]):
            tvar = workList[listIndexDecr-1]
            workList[listIndexDecr-1] = workList[listIndexDecr]
            workList[listIndexDecr] = tvar
            xChanged = True
        listIndexDecr = listIndexDecr - 1 

    # Return sorted list and stats
    return workList, step

#myList = [21,2,43,4,4,2,4,7,87,65,0,0,0,4,3,2,1212,21,212,32,433]
myList = random.sample(range(32), 4)
print("> "+str(myList))
myNewList,x = shakesort(myList)
print("< " + str(myNewList))
print("Finished in "+str(x-1)+" steps! List length was: "+str(len(myList)))
```

Comment: \$O(n^2)\$ doesn't necessarily mean the algorithm will use exactly \$n^2\$ steps. It simply means that as \$n\$ gets bigger, the number of steps used will tend towards \$n^2\$ (or less). You can read big O as "on the order of".

Comment: I think this algorithm is wrong and not exactly shakesort. the algorithm walks back AND forth in one loop rather than back XOR forth in one loop

Comment: `4² is 8` um, no. But that's about as relevant as the name being `shakesort` or [shaker sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort): asymptotic analysis is about _order of growth_ even _ignoring constant factors_.